# write xml to wcf for web service used for ssrs

Tags: xml, linq, web-services, wcf, reporting-services

I built linq query and converted it to xml with xDocument.
this issue is that I managed only to create it locally.

```
        XDocument document = new XDocument(
          new XElement("People",
                         from c in el
        join p in sl on c.eID equals p.sID
        select new XElement("Person", new XAttribute("ID", c.eID),
                     new XElement("Role", c.Role),
                     new XElement("RRCD", ConvertRole(c.cdRole) + c.cdRole),
                     new XElement("Department", p.department),
                     new XElement("Subject", p.subject))));
        document.Save("People.xml");
    }
```

I need to export it to a web service or wcf that only this option will populate xml web service that will be used for ssrs, how it can be done?